# How to wait for a response using JavaScript Fetch API before proceeding further?

Tags: javascript, promise, fetch-api, ecmascript-5

Is it possible to wait until the Javascript Fetch API to complete before executing the next code/instruction??

I want to wait for the response coming from the fetch. And then start executing the code further

```
function toggle(){
    console.log("hello 1");
    fetch('url')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {         
        console.log("hello 2");
        data.forEach(user => {
            let li = document.createElement("LI");
            let typ = document.createAttribute("class");
            typ.value = "list-group-item";
            li.attributes.setNamedItem(typ);
            li.innerHTML = `${user.username}`
            ul.appendChild(li);
            console.log("hello 3");
        })
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err.message()))

    let txtValue;
    filter = input.toUpperCase();
    let li = document.getElementsByTagName("LI");
    console.log("hello 4");
    for(let i = 0 ; i < li.length ; i++){
        txtValue = li[i].textContent || li[i].innerText;
        if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) === 0) {
            li[i].style.display = "block";
        } else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
    console.log("hello 5");
    document.body.appendChild(ul);
}
```

I expect the output on the console to be
Hello 1
Hello 2
Hello 3
Hello 4
Hello 5

but the actual output on console is
Hello 1
Hello 4
Hello 5
Hello 2
Hello 3

Comment: Just `await` each Promise

Comment: Does it have to be ES5?  If you could use ES6, the syntax is a breeze... `await fetch...`  Otherwise, you can just restructure this a bit.

Comment: all the code that you want to run after fetch, put them in `then`, otherwise use `async` function with `await fetch(url);`